# f#: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: matrix, f#

I am trying to work out precisely what the issue is with the following bit of code:

```
    let Vc = Vector.Create(n*m, (fun k -> 
    Vc_matrix.[ldIdx.[k], chrgIdx.[k]] ))
```

and I receive the following error message:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: row
 at Extreme.Mathematics.LinearAlgebra.LinearOperator`1.GG(Int32 , String )
 at Extreme.Mathematics.Matrix`1.get_Item(Int32 row, Int32 column)
```

The necessary matrices of ldIdx and chrgIdx are in place, so I am a bit confused! what else could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide MCVE?

Comment: (I mean you have to show simple input (`n`, `m`, `ldIdx`,...) and expected output)

Comment: okay will do. once sec please

Comment: The first index (``row``) passed to ``Vc_matrix`` in your second line is out of range, says the error message…

Comment: out of range meaning not the correct size?

Comment: Out of range means (in this case) that you passed a value that is not a valid index.

Comment: great thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: So, do you understand what is the problem?

Comment: I do now, thanks. But I will edit the above soon for completeness, perhaps you can shed more light on it. Please bare with me....

Comment: If you feel like something is not clear - you can join to [F# chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f). Btw, I advice you consider [F# slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) like central F# community